# Fill list/result with empty object to complete days in month

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an anonymous object returned by a EntityFramework query for all records that have data for the given time period.

```
var results = (from record in this.context.Records
                where record.Owner == owner && record.Date >= firstDay && record.Date <= lastDay
                select new
                {
                    record.Date,
                    PID = record.SubProcess.Process.Pid,
                    SPID = record.SubProcess.SPid,
                    ProcessName = record.SubProcess.Process.Name,
                    SubProcessName = record.SubProcess.Name,
                    record.Task,
                    record.SubTask,
                    record.Hours
                }).ToList();
```

How can I fill the dates that don't have data so that on my presentation layer, it shows the all days of the month but shows 0 for those days that don't have data?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found a workaround, I'm not sure if this is the best and/or efficient way of doing it but it works for my needs (atm).

I basically check if the result objects that don't have an entry for all the days in a month and inserted an empty object for that day.

```
var emptyResults = new List<object>();
            var days = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(firstDay.Year, firstDay.Month))
                .Select(day => new DateTime(firstDay.Year, firstDay.Month, day))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var date in days)
            {
                var exists = results.Any(x => x.Date == date);
                if (!exists)
                {
                    emptyResults.Add(new
                    {
                        Date = date,
                        PID = "",
                        SPID = "",
                        ProcessName = "",
                        SubProcessName = "",
                        Task = "",
                        SubTask = "",
                        Hours = 0
                    });
                }
            }

            var filledResults = results.Concat(emptyResults).ToList();
```

It doesn't look the most efficient way but it works for me. Please feel free to improve. Thanks